# How to find and remove partially transferred files after numerous failed rsync attempts

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have launched few rsyncs over sshfs(sftp) that leaves temporary files.
Is there any way how to cleanup those files?

I don't want to run rsync with `--partial` option, because there are many big files and it can take ages.

I tried to find them this way:

```
find -name ".*.??????"
```

and it finds some temporary files. But I'm not 100% sure if there are any files that are not discovered using this pattern.

Is this solution sufficient?

Comment: Are you able to use the delete option with rsync?

Comment: Yes and no. If I run it immediately after successful transfer, but now there are numerous changes in source directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

You could run rsync again with both the `--delete` and `--dry-run` options, and perhaps with `--itemize-changes`.  This would show you a list of all the changes that would be made.  Just take note of any deletions, ignoring changed files.  Unless your files have odd names, it should be obvious what are rsync temp files left behind and what are not.